# error al extraer datos de json con PHP

Tags: php, json

al leer desde MySQL un Json me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
 Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
  (
  [json] => {"port": 1, "app_id": "ltech_app1", "dev_id": "nodo_ltech", "counter": 120, "metadata": {"time": "2020-02-27T00:43:57.319462198Z", "airtime": 66816000, "gateways": [{"snr": 9, "rssi": -43, "time": "", "gtw_id": "eui-246f28ffff252590", "channel": 0, "altitude": 14, "latitude": 52.23736, "rf_chain": 0, "longitude": 5.97865, "timestamp": 832217207}], "data_rate": "SF7BW125", "frequency": 868.1, "modulation": "LORA", "coding_rate": "4/5"}, "payload_raw": "TmVzdG9yIHBydWViYSE=", "payload_fields": {"message": "Nestor prueba!"}, "hardware_serial": "00152C2E8F355A97"}
 )
 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [json] => "Nestor prueba!"
    )
```

)
pero cuando lo quiero explorar para sacar los datos que necesito me dice: 
 json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

este es el codigo

```
  <?php
                    // Define recursive function to extract nested values
                     function printValues($arr) {
                     global $count;
                     global $values;

                      // Check input is an array
                      if(!is_array($arr)){
                        die("ERROR: Input is not an array");
                      }

                      /*
                      Loop through array, if value is itself an array recursively call the
                      function else add the value found to the output items array,
                      and increment counter by 1 for each value found
                      */
                      foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
                        if(is_array($value)){
                          printValues($value);
                        } else{
                          $values[] = $value;
                          $count++;
                        }
                      }

                      // Return total count and values found in array
                      return array('total' => $count, 'values' => $values);
                     }

                    // Decode JSON data into PHP associative array format

                     $arr = ( json_decode($data, true) );

                    // Call the function and print all the values
                    $result = printValues($arr);

                    {?>
```

ahora si le fuerzo el mensaje reemplazando data por  la variable json y funciona perfectamente, que me esta faltando.

```
$json = '{"port": 1,"app_id": "ltech_app1","dev_id": "nodo_ltech","counter": 120,"metadata": {"time": "2020-02-27T00:43:57.319462198Z","airtime": 66816000,"gateways":[{"snr": 9, "rssi": -43, "time": "", "gtw_id": "eui-246f28ffff252590", "channel": 0, "altitude": 14, "latitude": 52.23736, "rf_chain": 0, "longitude": 5.97865, "timestamp": 832217207}],';
```

de esta manera obtengo los datos, conectándome a la base de MySQL lo que me devuelve el mensaje publicado al inicio

````
      // Crear conexión
    $cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin_ltech","xxxxxxx","admin_ltech");

    // Verifica la conexión
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
         echo "Error: Ups! Hubo problemas con la conexión.  Favor de intentar nuevamente.";
     } else {
         $strsql = "SELECT * FROM `lora`";
         $rs = mysqli_query($cn, $strsql);
         $total_rows = $rs->num_rows;

         if ($total_rows > 0 ) {
             while ($row = $rs->fetch_object()){
                 $data[] = $row;
             }

             //print_r($data);
             //echo( json_encode($data) );

         }
     }

    ?>    ```
````

Comment: Lo que te está devolviendo MySQL es un listado de objetos con una propiedad json, que contiene cadenas json. Puedes mostrar la parte de código donde asignas $data? Parece que el problema está en la asignación de data...

Comment: Hola ahi agregue el resto del codigo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la base de datos te devuelve un array de objetos y lo estás tratando en el código como un array. 
Para convertir un objeto en un array (antes de tratarlo como array) haz esto:

```
$array = (array) $objeto;
```

Esto convertirá tu objeto en un array asociativo

Comment: disculpame, podrias indicarme en que parte deberia colocarlo, es que recien estoy iniciandome en esto. Gracias

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer antes el json_decode. Aunque yo miraría antes como cojed los datos, ya que usas fetch_object...

Comment: podrias sugerirme otro metodo?